# how to pass the strings with quotes as function arguments values

Tags: r

I am facing issue as below where I am unable to use the string with quotes as a function argument value, here is program where i am creating a simple function to subset the data based on the string subset condition as below. I am using the rlang package curly curls {{ but this seems not working any thoughts

```r
adsl <- data.frame(SubjList=c(1:10), SAFFL=sample(c('Y','N'),10,replace = T))

subs <- function(data=NA,subset='SubjList!=""'){
data1 <- data %>% filter({{subset}})
  return(data1)
}

subs(data=adsl,subset = "SAFFL=='Y'")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

One solution is to use the `parse_expr()` function from the rlang package (https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/parse_expr.html) and the bang-bang operator:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

adsl <- data.frame(SubjList=c(1:10),
                   SAFFL=sample(c('Y','N'),10,
                                replace = T))

subs <- function(data, subset) {
  data1 <- data %>% filter(!!parse_expr((subset)))
  return(data1)
}

subs(data = adsl, subset = 'SAFFL == "Y"')
#>   SubjList SAFFL
#> 1        1     Y
#> 2        3     Y
#> 3        4     Y
#> 4        5     Y
#> 5        6     Y
#> 6        7     Y
#> 7       10     Y
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Original answer

One potential solution is to specify the variable (i.e. "SAFFL") and the value ("Y" or "N") separately, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

adsl <- data.frame(SubjList=c(1:10),
                   SAFFL=sample(c('Y','N'),10,
                                replace = T))

subs <- function(data, var, value){
  data1 <- data %>% filter(.data[[var]] == value)
  return(data1)
}

subs(data = adsl, var = "SAFFL", value = "Y")
#>   SubjList SAFFL
#> 1        4     Y
#> 2        5     Y
subs(data = adsl, var = "SAFFL", value = "N")
#>   SubjList SAFFL
#> 1        1     N
#> 2        2     N
#> 3        3     N
#> 4        6     N
#> 5        7     N
#> 6        8     N
#> 7        9     N
#> 8       10     N
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Does that work for your use-case? Or do you need to pass the variable and the value together for some reason?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, this will not work for me, i need to pass the entire string as argument value. Reason is that i am working on a shiny app where I will have to pass the entire string as a subset condition

Comment: I've just figured it out - I'll edit my answer @jkatom